# Qt 5.7. Компиляция IBASE плагина в Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qt, interbase

Необходимо собрать плагин QIBASE в Ubuntu 16.10 x64 для qt.5x. Мои действия описаны [здесь](http://sitefresh.net/articles/48-qt5-sborka-plagina-qibase-ubuntu-16-04.html).

Comment: Только под ubuntu? Метка стоит linux.

Comment: @0xdb у меня только ubuntu, в инете смотрел что в suse работает, сейчас метку добавлю, верно заметили.

Comment: @0xdb порекомендуйте поднять вопрос в рейтинге если есть возможность, а то он может так и останется не решённым.

Comment: А как? Голос я дал, в конкурс вы его подали. Наверное проблема в том, что вопрос довольно общий. Если соберу у себя  interbase, как это поможет вам? Я не могу при всём желании воссоздать полностью ваше окружение, включая все библиотеки и прочее.

Comment: @0xdb помочь это может хотя бы тем, что можно будет точно знать, что в определённой версии Ubuntu и Qt с определёнными командами (по дефолту) всё будет работать. Ещё можно рекомендовать друзьям проголосовать за, это позволит поднять вопрос в рейтинге и он будет лишний раз мозолить глаза.

Comment: Да, но у меня нету Ubuntu и пока не планируется.

Comment: @shaman888 не стоит превращать вопрос в огромное полонтно, в котором непонятно какую именно вы версию пытаетесь собрать. Оставьте шаги для воспроизведения и актуальную ошибку для последней версии (5.7?)

Comment: @shaman888 на оффсайте кстати есть шаги для комипляции под 5.8: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qibase

Comment: @PashaPash видел, но там указаны пути которых у меня в системе нет.

Comment: @PashaPash благодаря такому полотну я пытаюсь показать общую картину компиляции ibase плагина, это помогает мне в поисках ошибок. К тому же готовый ответ я планирую описать вкратце и по существу.

Comment: @shaman888 вопрос тоже должен быть в кратце и по существу. Сейчас совершенно непонятно, что же вы пытаетесь сделать. Собрать под 5.7? Выяснить, почему у вас нет путей, которые указаны в faq для 5.8? Собрать под конкретную более раннюю версию?

Comment: @PashaPash пытаюсь собрать плагин и выявить все возможные причины проблем, дабы в будущем не повторять прежних ошибок. Я не знаю под какой версией у меня получится произвести сборку плагина в первую очередь, поэтому собираю для всех версий. Проблема считаю актуальная. В интернете не нашёл рабочего варианта настройки сборки для моей конфигурации. Можно было бы и поддержать вопрос голосом.

Comment: "Я не знаю под какой версией у меня получится произвести сборку плагина в первую очередь" - собирайте ту версию, которая нужна вам, а не ту которая получится. Почему вы не преслушиваетесь к советам и не редактируете вопрос, чтобы он был более конкретным. Вы задали вопрос по 5.7, и не надо пытаться спасти человечество. Полотно можете оставить себе, если оно вам помогает, здесь же не надо публиковать его полностью.

Comment: Да кстати, почему 5.7, а не рекомендуемая 5.8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сборка была проверена на Ubuntu 16.10 и Debian jessie. Под Debian команды с `sudo` выполнил в терминале с `root`.
Для сборки QT пользовался [вики](http://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git)

В `/etc/apt/source.list` должны быть включены исходники - `deb-src`.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep qt5-default
sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0-dev
sudo apt-get install firebird-dev
```

Склонировал исходные коды и собрал QT5.7:

```
cd /usr/src # или любую другую папку по-усмотрению с правами на запись
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git

cd qt5;
git checkout 5.7

perl init-repository

./configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

Конфигуратор ничего не нашёл для InterBase:

```
  SQL drivers:
    DB2 .................. no
    InterBase ............ no
    MySQL ................ yes (plugin)
    OCI .................. no
    ODBC ................. yes (plugin)
    PostgreSQL ........... yes (plugin)
    SQLite 2 ............. no
    SQLite ............... yes (plugin, using bundled copy)
    TDS .................. yes (plugin)

make -j4

# make install # т.к. developers-build, нет необходимости
```

Собрал плагин для firebird по этому [источнику](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qibase)

```
export QTDIR=/usr/src/qt5
export PATH=$QTDIR/qtbase/bin:$PATH

cd $QTDIR/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/ibase

# для обхода ошибки: /usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lgds
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so /usr/lib/libgds.so

qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include" "LIBS+=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lfbclient" ibase.pro
make
```

Следующая ошибка уже известна и ожидает лечения [баг](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53375)

> /usr/include/c++/6/cstdlib:75:25: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file
>   or directory
>        #include_next 
>                                ^

Поправляем сгенерированный Makefile и повторяем `make`:

```
INCPATH       = -I. -isystem /usr/include
--> меняем на
INCPATH       = -I. -I/usr/include
```

Вывод:

```
rm -f libqsqlibase.so
g++ -Wl,--no-undefined -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/src/qt5/qtbase/lib -shared -o libqsqlibase.so .obj/main.o .obj/qsql_ibase.o .obj/moc_qsql_ibase_p.o  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lfbclient -lgds -L/usr/src/qt5/qtbase/lib -lQt5Sql -lQt5Core -lpthread
mv -f libqsqlibase.so ../../../../plugins/sqldrivers/

-rwxr-xr-x 1 db src 1241008 May  1 23:55 ../../../../plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlibase.so
```

Вроде всё. Собралось без особых ошибок. Тестовая программка показывает, что плагин ibase теперь доступен:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << "drivers available:" << QSqlDatabase::drivers();
    QCoreApplication::exit(0);
}
```

> drivers available: ("QIBASE", "QSQLITE", "QMYSQL", "QMYSQL3", "QODBC", "QODBC3", "QPSQL", "QPSQL7", "QTDS", "QTDS7")

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58379/discussion-on-answer-by-0xdb-qt-5-7--ibase---ubuntu-16-10).

Comment: библиотека скомпилировалась, однако не подключается к проекту, не пойму в чём проблема.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664883/qibase-driver-not-loaded

Comment: разобрался, ошибка исчезла. спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад, что получилось. Если у вас появится немного времени, поправте всё таки вопрос, там много чего лишнего.