# Невозможно открыть файл, но он существует. make

Tags: linux, qt, makefile

Для Qt 5.6. При попытки [компиляции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602903/qt-5-7-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-ibase-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-ubuntu-16-10) make выдаёт ошибку.

```
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: невозможно открыть /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../../lib/libgds.so: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

Однако:

```
user:~$ cd /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../../lib/
user:/usr/lib$ l *gds*
lgds.so@  libgds.so@  libgds.so.0@
```

В чём может быть проблема и как её решить? [Полный лог](http://sitefresh.net/pages/error-log-n1-ibase-qt.html).

UPD 1:

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so
sudo chmod 777 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.2
sudo chmod 777 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.2.5.6 
ls -l /usr/lib/libgds.so
lrwxrwxrwx 3 root root 20 дек 13 10:47 /usr/lib/libgds.so -> libfbclient.so.2.5.6
```

UPD 2:

```
file -L /usr/lib/libgds.so
/usr/lib/libgds.so: cannot open `/usr/lib/libgds.so' (No such file or directory)
locate libfbclient.so.2.5.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.2.5.6
```

Comment: Права на чтение проверьте.

Comment: @aleks.andr проверил, обновил вопрос

Comment: какую битность имеет библиотека? см. вывод `$ file -L /usr/lib/libgds.so`. подозреваю, что 32 бита. а линковать пытаетесь, видимо, с 64-битным кодом.

Comment: Автор, вы ослепли? :) У вас путь ведёт в системный */usr/lib* вместо */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*. Не говоря уже о том, что `/lib` в конце пути лишний. Проверять текущие и другие пути надо командами `readlink`, например, `readlink -f $PWD`.

Comment: @0andriy не ясно в каком конкретно месте проверять нужно. Вопрос обновил.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin исходя из locate libfbclient.so.2.5.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.2.5.6
 и выше представленного предполагаю что libgds.so ссылается на x64 библиотеку

Comment: ну так нет же такого файла, к которому пытается обращаться программа `/usr/bin/ld.gold`! нет у вас файла `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../../lib/libgds.so`, или, сокращая двоеточия, `/usr/lib/libgds.so`, о чём свидетельствует приведённый вами результат выполнения команды `$ file -L /usr/lib/libgds.so`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin что же тогда должно означать следующее:  ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.2.5.6
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 865256 окт  3  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.2.5.6
:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/libgds.so
lrwxrwxrwx 3 root root 20 дек 13 10:47 /usr/lib/libgds.so -> libfbclient.so.2.5.6

Comment: то, что вы и видите: символическая ссылка `/usr/lib/libgds.so` указывает на файл `/usr/lib/libfbclient.so.2.5.6`, который либо не существует., либо тоже является ссылкой, указывающей на несуществующую цель.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin file -L  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.2.5.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.2.5.6: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=c1741d37dbc77b20420cb5e1dd70867432f93a6f, stripped

Comment: ничего не понял. какое отношение ` /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.2.5.6` может иметь к `/usr/lib/libfbclient.so.2.5.6`? вы, видимо, запутались, и меня пытаетесь запутать.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вы правы, я ошибочно решил, что libgds.so ссылается на файл /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.2.5.6 поскольку это единственный путь выданный командой locate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/libfbclient.so 
sudo rm /usr/lib/libgds.so 
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.2.5.6 /usr/lib/libfbclient.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.2.5.6 /usr/lib/libgds.so
```

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, для чего этот набор команд :)

Comment: @gil9red поправил. Первые две строки удаляют ссылки, вторые создают. Проблема была в том что ссылки указывали на несуществующие файлы.