# QIBASE driver not loaded

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu

Файл библиотеки размещал так же в папку с проектом. Система ubuntu 16.04 x64 qt 5.8 производил сборку [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602903/qt-5-7-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-ibase-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-ubuntu-16-10).

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QPluginLoader>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);


    QPluginLoader loader;
    loader.setFileName("/usr/src/qt5/qtbase/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlibase.so");
    qDebug() << loader.load();
    qDebug() <<  loader.isLoaded();
    qDebug() << loader.errorString();

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QIBASE");
    qDebug() << QString("Cannot open database") << db.lastError();

    QCoreApplication::exit(0);
}
```

qibase.pro

```
QT += core
QT -= gui
QT += sql

CONFIG += c++11
TARGET = qibase
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

console

```
true
true
"Unknown error"
QSqlDatabase: QIBASE driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
"Cannot open database" QSqlError("", "Driver not loaded", "Driver not loaded")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что нужно было использовать qmake той же версии, что и откомпилированный плагин qibase. После создания правильного комплекта сборки проблема исчезла.