# Qt, не подключается к базе данных

Tags: qt, ubuntu, firebird

База данных firebird. Система ubuntu 22.04. qt 5.15.2

```
void testConn(){
    //qDebug() << "Доступные драйверы:" << QSqlDatabase::drivers();
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("QIBASE");

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QIBASE");
    db.setHostName("172.18.110.56");
    db.setPort(3050);
    db.setDatabaseName("C:/ACS/Base/ACS.fdb");
    db.setUserName("login");
    db.setPassword("pass");




/*
        db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
        db.setPort(3050);
        db.setDatabaseName("/home/nikit/testDB/ACSutf.fdb");
        db.setUserName("SYSDBA");
        db.setPassword("masterkey");
*/

    qDebug() << "Host Name:" << db.hostName();
    qDebug() << "Port:" << db.port();
    qDebug() << "Database Name:" << db.databaseName();
    qDebug() << "User Name:" << db.userName();
    int stat = db.open();
    qDebug()<< stat;
    qDebug() << "OH NO: " << db.lastError().text();
```

Попытка подключения к локальной базе данных извечно выдает ошибку рода

- нет доступа к `/tmp/firebird`. Выдача прав через `sudo chown :adm /tmp/firebird/fb_init`,`sudo chown :adm /tmp/firebird/fb50_trace`,`chmod -R 777`работает лишь на один запуск, затем сбрасываются.
- Исли право на файлы есть, то `user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login.`
- Если в коде добавлять строки:

```
db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
db.setPort(3050);
```

то он уходит в лютую истерию с ошибкой
`Invalid connection string - Cannot transliterate character between character sets - Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character Error opening database`

Попытка подключения к удаленному ресурсу
`Invalid connection string - Cannot transliterate character between character sets - Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character Error opening database`

Товарищи, прошу помочь, сил уже нет, chatgpt водит по кругу, на форумах пустота

Comment: Для начала попробуй подключиться к этой базе с помощью isql.

Comment: @user13964273, спасибо за ответ. Удаленное подключение через isql работает. Внештатных проблем нет. Подключение к локальной таблице работает, если не указывать адреса и порта, тоже работает. Обнаруженная проблема, firebird ноет, что нет прав к папке и файлам в /tmp/firebird. Попытка выдачи прав через chmode, chown работает только на сеанс консоли, после закрытия затираются. Подозреваю, что права затираются политикой безопасности. Лечения не знаю. Читал, что выдача прав на папку является плохим тоном.

Comment: Читай Release Notes. И не пытайся использовать Embedded режим если ты не в группе firebird. С неправильно сформированным UTF-8, стало быть, в отладчик Qt.

Comment: @user13964273, подскажите, как исправить эту ситуацию, не совсем разбираюсь в этом. Мне нужно пересобирать драйвер interbase/qt с другой конфигурацией? Если да, подскажите нужную, пожалуйста

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602903/qt-5-7-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-ibase-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-ubuntu-16-10. Действовал согласно этому источнику, по принципу " у человека получилось, у меня тоже получится". Собирал qt версии 5.15. но плагин interbase сразу нашелся, не пришлось собирать.      Я ошибся где-то, напишите что удалить, а что пересобирать, пожалуйста, заранее благодарен

Comment: @user13964273, неправильно сформированная кодировка utf8 со стороны qt, или firebird?

Comment: Раз isql работает, значит проблема в Qt. Учитывая, что у тебя в строке подключения только латиница, такой проблемы вообще не должно возникать по идее.

Comment: Это правда, @user13964273. Я попытаюсь полностью удалить qt, и установить заново. Хотелось бы уточнить, строка конфигуратора корректна для меня, (из источника https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602903/qt-5-7-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-ibase-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-ubuntu-16-10)?

Comment: Дополнительный вопрос с доступом к каталогу /tmp/firebird. На текущий момент моя учётная запись состоит в группе firebird, а сама группа имеет права sudo, adm. Когда я пытаюсь подключиться к своей локальной БД в целях тестирования, в каталоге временных файлов создаются временные файлы, с правами по умолчанию (-rw-rw------), при попытке открытия локальной БД падает по причине нет доступа к временым файлам. Если выдать права, работает. Но при пересоздания временных файлов разрешения сбрасываются. Лечение?

Comment: Не подключаться к локальной базе. Подключаться к локальному серверу.

Comment: Установил локаль на en_US.UTF-8 .Полностью переустановил qt, используя онлайн установщик. Новый каталог /opt/qt5. Подключил qmake: `QMAKE = /opt/qt5/5.15.2/gcc_64/bin/qmake`, `QT+= sql`, `CONFIG+=utf8`. Установил ibase драйвер из сообщения другого пользователя. > sudo apt install libqt5sql5-ibase. Сослался на эту библиотеку, которая лежала в /usr/lib/x86....     `LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/ -lqsqlibase`. Доступных драйверов сократилось до 2х, один из них был qibase. Попытался подключиться, та же ошибка с неверной кодировкой. @user13964273, прошу помочь снова

Answer (score 1):

Драйвер руками собирается для винды. В линуксе все проще

> sudo apt install libqt5sql5-ibase

Comment: Предварительно ничего не надо удалять/переустанавливать/пересобирать?

Comment: нет. это чисто драйвер для qt. естественно сам FB должен стоять